# need a method to find a value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I have a HashMap as following:

```
 Key Value
  A    5
  B    3
  C    10
  D    4
  E    1
  F    11
```

I need to find the one with highest value, what do you suggest me to do? should I sort them and get the first one or there is any other faster way?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you may also keep track of the largest value in the HashMap yourself as new key value pairs are inserted into the HashMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much more easily solved by using a `SortedMap` and passing in a `Comparator` for the values:

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("A", 5);
map.put("B", 3);
map.put("C", 10);
map.put("D", 4);
map.put("E", 1);
map.put("F", 11);
map.put("G", 11);
map.put("H", 10);

TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new Comparator<String>() {
  // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.
  @Override
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (map.get(a) >= map.get(b)) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    } // returning 0 would merge keys
  }
});
sorted.putAll(map);


Entry<String, Integer> first = sorted.firstEntry();
System.out.println("Highest value: " + first.getValue() + is for key: " + first.getKey());

// If duplicate keys are never a concern, you can stop here.  Otherwise, one may 
// continue below to find all keys that may be mapped to an equal highest value:
List<String> others = new LinkedList<String>();
for (Entry<String, Integer> entries : sorted.entrySet()) {
  if (entries.getValue().equals(first.getValue())) {
    others.add(entries.getKey());
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

System.out.println("All keys mapped to this highest value: " + others);
```

Prints out:

```
Highest value: 11 is for key: G
All keys mapped to this highest value: [G, F]
```

Comment: I have a bit of doubt whether the TreeMap can still be used as a Map after this.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I just have a bit of trouble imagining how get() and containsKey() will work.

Comment: @nhahtdh The logic is sound. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/24396

Comment: This solution breaks the contract written in the Map interface, and is fragile. Read the comments in the link for more information. -1

Comment: @nhahtdh I updated to prevent the overwriting of keys with the same values.  This example should resolve what the poster is looking for "the one with the highest value".  Agree that better solutions exist, but for this scenario, without adopting any third party libraries (Guava), this should suffice.

Comment: @Cuga: The code is at best patchy (and most of the functions in TreeMap is broken). If you have already coded this far, writing a reverse map from Integer -> List<String> might be better.

Comment: It's not really patchy.  The `Comparator` is an anonymous class, used only in one location and for one specific purpose, so the `equals` contract with `compareTo` doesn't really come into play in this closed-example.  It completely solves the OP's quest which is just to find the one key.  After gotten, she can continue to use the original `HashMap` as she desires.  Only use the `TreeMap` for this one task-- finding the key with the max value in its own function, and then she'll always be fine.

Comment: @nhahtdh To be clear, I'm not saying he should ditch the `HashMap` and use a `TreeMap` from here on out-- merely to only use it for the purpose of finding the sought-answer, ideally in its own, focused function designed to do exactly this which will return the result.

Comment: @Cuga: Your method is no better than looping through all the values and get the maximum value. The TreeMap is totally unnecessary and has a bad example of implementing Comparator for TreeMap.

Comment: That's not at all true.  Simply looping thru and keeping a record of the max value will still need special care for recording duplicate keys.  In any event, it's an entirely acceptable solution to completely address the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advice to do sorting for a search requirement. As adviced by @David Lam, you can perform a search(iteration) as below to find the highest value key.

```
    Set<String> keys = myMap.keySet();
    Iterator<String> keyIter = keys.iterator();
    String highestValueKey = null;
    while(keyIter.hasNext()){
         String key = keyIter.next();
         if(highestValueKey == null){
             highestValueKey = key;
         }else if(myMap.get(key).intValue() > myMap.get(highestValueKey).intValue()){
             highestValueKey = key;
         }
    }
```

In the end, `highestValueKey` will have reference to highest value element's key.

Answer (score 1):

just iterate through the keys and keep track of the highest one O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do the "find the largest value" operation frequently, I suggest you use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Else if you are inserting values into the HashMap and have complete control over it, then keep track of the largest value as you insert values into the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

EDIT:
You will need to use HashMap either way as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/548634)

Comment: TreeMap doesn't work here, since it order based on key, while OP wants to find the value.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use Bubble Sort to find the highest value